# memory access in assembly syntax differences

Tags: assembly, syntax, mips

I was wondering if is there any difference between these

[image]

Answer (score 0):

- In the first example the `$t0` register will contain the address of `value` after the instruction.

  The assembler will replace the `la` instruction by a "real" MIPS instruction - such as `addiu` if `value` is located in the lower 32 kiB of memory (which is typically not the case on a "real" MIPS CPU):

  ```
  addiu $t0, $zero, value
  lw $t1, 0($t0)
  ```

  If the address of `value` is not located within the first (or last) 32 kiB of memory the assembler will replace this instruction by two instructions:

  ```
  lui $t0, high_bits_of(value)
  addiu $t0, $t0, low_bits_of(value)
  lw $t1, 0($t0)
  ```
- In the second example `$t0` will contain `0` after the instruction.

  If the address of `value` is not located within the first 32 kiB of memory the program will not work!

Comment: _"If the address of value is not located within the first 32 kiB"_  Or the last 32 kiB.  _"the program will not work"_ In this case the code shouldn't even assemble/link, but maybe that's what you meant.

Comment: The MARS/SPIM simulators assemblers will use in second case the `$1` aka `$at` (assembler temporary) register to load the `value` address into it, and then it will use `lw $t1, 0($at)` to load the word from memory. So it will both work, and assemble without error, but only due to fundamental change of final machine code. @Michael JFYI.